# Bibtex bibliography styles (acm)

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, bibliographies

Many of the books used the order of references in this form 
[image]

I use `Bibtex`, and I want to arrange the references as in the form above.

I looked at the types of styles and found the nearest arrangement to above form is `acm`

But the letters of the name are large and the letters of a word `and` are large.

What is the solution ?

Is there another style similar to the above form?

For example,

```
 \documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%Includes "References" in the table of contents
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}


%Begining of the document
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\medskip

\section{First Section}
This document is an example of BibTeX using in bibliography management. Three items are cited: \textit{The \LaTeX\ Companion} book \cite{latexcompanion}, the Einstein journal paper \cite{einstein}, and the Donald Knuth's website \cite{knuthwebsite}. The \LaTeX\ related items are \cite{latexcompanion,knuthwebsite}. 

\medskip

%Sets the bibliography style to UNSRT and imports the 
%bibliography file "samples.bib".
\bibliographystyle{acm}
\bibliography{sample}

\end{document}
```

The bibliography file

```
    @article{einstein,
    author =       "Albert Einstein",
    title =        "{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. ({German})
        [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]",
    journal =      "Annalen der Physik",
    volume =       "322",
    number =       "10",
    pages =        "891--921",
    year =         "1905",
    DOI =          "http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004"
}

@book{latexcompanion,
    author    = "Michel Goossens and Frank Mittelbach and Alexander Samarin",
    title     = "The \LaTeX\ Companion",
    year      = "1993",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    address   = "Reading, Massachusetts"
}

@misc{knuthwebsite,
    author    = "Donald Knuth",
    title     = "Knuth: Computers and Typesetting",
    url       = "http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/\~{}uno/abcde.html"
}
```

The order of the reference as in the picture

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is much more easier to customize `biblatex` and `biber` instead of `bibtex`.

So the following is based on `biblatex` (try `texdoc biblatex` to read the documentation).

With the package option

```
style=numeric,
```

you get the numeric layout you want, with

```
giveninits=true
```

the first names are only shown with there initials and with the command

```
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given}
```

all names are printed as "familyname, firstname".

So the following MWE

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{einstein,
    author =       "Albert Einstein",
    title =        "{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. ({German})
        [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]",
    journal =      "Annalen der Physik",
    volume =       "322",
    number =       "10",
    pages =        "891--921",
    year =         "1905",
    DOI =          "http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004"
}

@book{latexcompanion,
    author    = "Michel Goossens and Frank Mittelbach and Alexander Samarin",
    title     = "The \LaTeX\ Companion",
    year      = "1993",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    address   = "Reading, Massachusetts"
}

@misc{knuthwebsite,
    author    = "Donald Knuth",
    title     = "Knuth: Computers and Typesetting",
    url       = "http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/\~{}uno/abcde.html"
}
\end{filecontents}


\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[%
  style=numeric, 
  sortcites,
  backend=biber,
  giveninits=true % <===================================================
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given} % <============================


\begin{document}

\section{First Section}
This document is an example of BibTeX using in bibliography management. 
Three items are cited: \textit{The \LaTeX\ Companion} book 
\cite{latexcompanion}, the Einstein journal paper \cite{einstein}, and 
the Donald Knuth's website \cite{knuthwebsite}. The \LaTeX\ related 
items are \cite{latexcompanion,knuthwebsite}. 

\medskip

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

should give you the result you want:

[image: resulting bibliography]

If that is not what you need please specify in your question how a book should be printed in the bibliography, how an article, an online reference etc. That is not clear with your inserted image ...

## Edit:

To change the sign after a unit you can add for example the following command

```
\renewcommand*\newunitpunct{\addcomma\space}
```

to get a comma, followed by a space.

So with the following MWE

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{einstein,
    author =       "Albert Einstein",
    title =        "{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. ({German})
        [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]",
    journal =      "Annalen der Physik",
    volume =       "322",
    number =       "10",
    pages =        "891--921",
    year =         "1905",
    DOI =          "http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004"
}

@book{latexcompanion,
    author    = "Michel Goossens and Frank Mittelbach and Alexander Samarin",
    title     = "The \LaTeX\ Companion",
    year      = "1993",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    address   = "Reading, Massachusetts"
}

@misc{knuthwebsite,
    author    = "Donald Knuth",
    title     = "Knuth: Computers and Typesetting",
    url       = "http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/\~{}uno/abcde.html"
}
\end{filecontents}


\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[%
  style=numeric, 
  sortcites,
  backend=biber,
  giveninits=true % <===================================================
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given} % <============================
\renewcommand*\newunitpunct{\addcomma\space} % <========================


\begin{document}

\section{First Section}
This document is an example of BibTeX using in bibliography management. 
Three items are cited: \textit{The \LaTeX\ Companion} book 
\cite{latexcompanion}, the Einstein journal paper \cite{einstein}, and 
the Donald Knuth's website \cite{knuthwebsite}. The \LaTeX\ related 
items are \cite{latexcompanion,knuthwebsite}. 

\medskip

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

you get the following result:

[image: new resulting bibliography]

## Edit2:

Add after `\renewcommand*\newunitpunct` a redefinition of command `\finalnamedelim`:

```
\renewcommand*\newunitpunct{\addcomma\space} % <========================
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{%
  \addspace\bibstring{and}\space}%
% <===== ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ =============================================
```

That delets the comma you do not want.

Comment: Process started

This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9.6350 64-bit) The top-level auxiliary file: build/gg.aux I found no \citation commands---while reading file build/gg.aux I found no \bibdata command---while reading file build/gg.aux I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file build/gg.aux (There were 3 error messages)

Process exited with error(s)

Comment: Thank you very much ... Although the question has been a long time but you helped me ... I am very grateful to you ...

Comment: See your answer to Ref. 3. There is no apostrophes between the name of the reference and the name of the author

Comment: There should be  apostrophes between the name of the author and the reference address.

Comment: see new update .....

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to switch from `bibtex` to `biblatex`, you'll just need to load the `biblatex` package with option `style=numeric`. Here's a MWE that worked for me:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[style=numeric,sortcites,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\bibliography{sample.bib}

%Begining of the document
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\medskip

\section{First Section}
This document is an example of BibTeX using in bibliography management. Three items are cited: \textit{The \LaTeX\ Companion} book \cite{latexcompanion}, the Einstein journal paper \cite{einstein}, and the Donald Knuth's website \cite{knuthwebsite}. The \LaTeX\ related items are \cite{latexcompanion,knuthwebsite}. 

\medskip

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do not give the right result as requested

Comment: @Emadkareem What is different? Please explain better ...

Comment: @Emadkareem I do not see a difference. Please explain better what you need ...